# php class inside variable within class

Tags: php

im not an experienced programmer and im trying to understand a problem im having with a class i created.

i have a private variable in class A, this private variable stores the result of a query to mysql db, and im accessing this variable through a public function in class A.

My goal is to echo out the value of private variable through the public function. My problem its that this private variable is converted in a class when it stores the query results.

here the var_dump of private variable

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
    ["count(*)"]=> string(1) "8" 
}
```

im realy confused on how to echo out the number "8"

im trying this:

```
echo $this->private
```

but as expected php doesnt work just like that and is telling me this:

```
"Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

here is the code:

```
class Quiz {

    private $db;
    private $query;
    private $questions;
    private $answers;
    private $total;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnection();      
    }

    public function NumRows ($quiz) {
        $this->query = $this->db->prepare("Select count(*) FROM ".$quiz."");
        $this->query->execute();
        $this->total = $this->query->fetchObject();
        var_dump($this->total);
        echo $this->total;
    }


}


$quiz = new Quiz();
$quiz->NumRows("01_ospf");
```

Comment: It would be helpful with a piece of code.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count`. Then: `echo $quiz->getPrivate()->count;`

Comment: Never EVER `echo` in any function except only one in your ENTIRE codebase: a function which looks like `render($template, array $data)` which calls `extract()` and then `include $template;`. Anywhere else, use return values properly instead.

Comment: Never EVER initialize heavy resources like a db connection in the constructor. This makes testing (mocking) impossible.

Comment: thank you for your reply Flavius, do you know where can i get a example of echoing a function with out echo... because i need to print some html.

Comment: I think what Flavius is stating, is that you return the value on the function call, and echo that out.
Such as `echo $quiz->NumRows("01_ospf");`.
While I don't agree with him saying "never ever", especially without an explanation of why, he has some point.
A function call in an echo will happen before the string is finalized for an echo.
So if you call echo and a function that echos in that echo, the function echo will execute first.
Which can be quite confusing for a newbie.

Not entirely sure what the point is for the render and extract calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->private` is an object, so you need to access the property. The property is named `count(*)`. So use this:

```
echo $this->private->{"count(*)"};
```

You should give the column an alias so you don't have to use this convoluted syntax. E.g. if you do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ...
```

then you can write:

```
echo $this->private->count;
```